# State is lost when tab is discarded for React in Chrome

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome

I have a web app in React

I use componentDidMount to do some AJAX calls and get some data from the server as recommended by the React team

I have noticed that when the tab is discarded and reloaded once I hit it, the state is gone and componentDidMount is not being called again

Therefore the app is being rendered with default data

Anyone else experienced that?

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 0):

If you had shared your code then it would have been easy to address the problem.However, I would take a guess on your code, i think you have used anchor tag for tab.Use `Link` component from your `react-router-dom` .Since `Link` component by default has `event.preventDefault()`.

```
<Link to="#tab" name="tabName">Tab</Link>
```